# Batch folder creation based on part of file name, without keeping extension

Tags: batch-file

Trying to create a script that will take the third token of a file name, create a folder based on it and move the associated file to that folder.

Have got this so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=D:\Sourcedir"
PUSHD %sourcedir%
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "*.pdf"'
 ) DO (  
 ECHO MD %%c
 ECHO MOVE "%%a %%b %%c %%d" .\%%c\
)
POPD
GOTO :EOF
```

Only problem is the folder being created is including the file extension where as I just need the folder to be named the third token.

Example file name:

> "File Number 10.pdf

Expected folder name:

> 10

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use `delims=`? This will remove delimiter, and take whole line to `%%a`.
Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=D:\Sourcedir"
PUSHD %sourcedir%
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "*.pdf"'
 ) DO (  
 ECHO MD %%~nc
 ECHO MOVE "%%a %%b %%c" .\%%~nc\
)
POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

When no `delims=` set, it will use space.   So `%%c` will be `10.pdf`, `~n` is to extract its **n**ame part.

This is based on your question, which you can concatenate `%%a` `%%b` `%%c` together with `spaces`, then it's simple.
If your filenames are more complicated, then an inner `for` loop is better.
  -- Which another question already gave a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can run 2 for loops get the full name in the first, then split the name in the second loop, get the 3rd token, create the directory and then copy the actual file name from the first loop.

This way you do not need to try and patch the name together again, I know it works, but it is ugly and not prefered:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "sourcedir=D:\Sourcedir"
pushd %sourcedir%
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
    set "var=%%a"
   for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ("!var!") do (
     echo md "%%~ni"
     echo move "%%~a" "%%~ni"
  )
)
popd
goto EOF
```

For more information on these commands, see help for each from `cmd.exe` i.e

```
for /?
set /?
setlocal /?
```

`set` and `setlocal` has very specific information regarding delayed expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative, which will just use the last space delimited string/number, regardless of how many there are, *(if there are none it will use the whole filename)*!

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In ("D:\Sourcedir\*.pdf") Do Call :L "%%A"
Exit /B

:L
Set "F=%~n1"
Set "F=%F: ="&Set "F=%"
If Not Exist "%~dp1%F%\" MD "%~dp1%F%"
Move /Y %1 "%~dp1%F%"
```

And if you wanted to move only those which have at least one space, you can include that inside the `For` parentheses.

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In ("D:\Sourcedir\* *.pdf") Do Call :L "%%A"
Exit /B

:L
Set "F=%~n1"
Set "F=%F: ="&Set "F=%"
If Not Exist "%~dp1%F%\" MD "%~dp1%F%"
Move /Y %1 "%~dp1%F%"
```